# windows 10 client won't connect network share

Tags: windows, active-directory, network-share

I recently added a Win10 client to our local domain.  This one machine (of ~20) cannot connect to the ReadyNAS 2100 NAS we use for file storage.  We add file shares (hosted on the NAS) to all Windows 10 clients using GPO. The domain is a samba AD domain (Univention Corporate Server).

Troubleshooting so far:

- I can ping the NAS from the client (hostname and IP address).
- nslookup successfully resolves the NAS by hostname.
- GPO modelling indicates the file share policy is successfully applied to the client
- All other clients receive the same GPO (in the same ou) and can access the shares
- I can't access the NAS web interface - I get a 'connection refused error'.
- The problematic client can only 'see' four machines when browsing the network in Windows Explorer, but can connect to everything (except the NAS) by IP address.

I cant work out if this is a DNS issue, a kerberos issue, or some strange faulty hardware/software issue.

Anybody got troubleshooting suggestions?

Comment: If you can successfully ping the NAS by name from the affected client then it isn't a DNS issue. Does the user have the appropriate file and folder permissions? Also, in this instance, nslookup isn't a good tool. Nslookup has it's own DNS resolver and is querying the DNS servers directly. What your Nslookup test did was verify that the DNS server could resolve the name correctly. It did not tell you that the DNS client resolver on the affected machine could resolve the name correctly.

Comment: @joeqwerty - The same user can access the shares from other machines. Is there a way to check if the affected machine can resolve DNS without using nslookup?

Comment: You've confirmed DNS resolution with your ping test. If you can ping by name and the ping resolves the name then you've successfully tested the DNS client resolver on the affected machine. My guess at this point would be the Windows Firewall, a third party firewall, or antivirus/antimalware software on the affected machine.

Answer (score 2):

Resolved.  Issue was that the NAS is so old it runs SMB1 - which is disbaled in recent Win10 versions.  Thanks for the help/suggestions